# AWS lambda throwing import error because of URLLIB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, urllib

Im running a python script on aws lambda and its throwing the following error.

```
 {
   "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168",
   "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
   "stackTrace": [] }
```

It was running perfectly an hour ago , and even after I have made no deployments , it seems to be failing.

my python version is 3.7.
and Im only using urllib to parse and unquote urls .
namely

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
```

and

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
```

like its mentioned in the GitHub url I can upgrade my python version, but doing so would break other things.
Are there any alternative librries I can use to get the same result?

from the GitHub link , it shows urllib no longer supports OpenSSL<1.1.1 but somehow some of our higher environments the same scripts is running without issues.

Comment: "even after I have made no deployments , it seems to be failing" if that's true that's very strange.  Are you packaging `ssl` module yourself?  "my python version is 3.7 ... would break other things" well, [3.7 is going to be EOL very soon](https://devguide.python.org/versions/), so I'm guessing that's part of your issue.

Comment: Nope, not packaging the ssl module myself.

Answer (score 10):

specifying my `urllib3` to 1.26.15 in the `requirement.txt` file based on this https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168#issuecomment-1535838106 thread fixed this error.

Comment: The suggested solution in this link here fixed it for me. i.e  pinning an older version of requests to requests==2.29.0 in requirements.txt. I am using python 3.8

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade you AWS Lambda function runtime to Python 3.10 and it should work.

Comment: It worked, tried lot of answer, this one was simple worked quickly

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this because of the following pip requrement in my Pipenv file:

```
requests = ">= 2.28.2, < 3"
```

What went wrong:

- requests depends on urllib3
- this dependency changed in requests 2.30.

  - `requests/setup.py v2.29.0: "urllib3>=1.21.1,<1.27"`
  - `requests/setup.py v2.30.0: "urllib3>=1.21.1,<3"`

Effectively the minor version upgrade of reguests 2.29 to 2.30 caused a major version upgrade of urllib3 version 1.x to 2.x. Which is backward incompatile and required a newer OpenSSL library on the system.

My simple fix was to change my `requests` dependency to

```
requests = ">= 2.28.2, < 2.29.0"
```

There will be similar errors with other pip dependencies which depend on urllib3. For example The `bigtable` package and many more.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue using an older version of the urllib library when I was installing all the other libraries required by my code:

```
python -m pip install urllib3==1.26.16 --no-deps -t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve it by specifying the lower version of urllib in your requirements.txt file.

```
requests
urllib3<2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [GH issue](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168) in the error message, you'll see that the problem only occurs to  Python >=3.7 but <3.10

upgrade to python 3.10 and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I hacked at this quite a bit and ended up doing a few things.

I'm using python 3.8.16

1. I installed the openssl11

   ```
   sudo yum install openssl11
   ```
2. found the existing runtime.

```
whereis openssl
openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/lib64/openssl /usr/include/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
```

3. renamed   the old openssl

   ```
   sudo mv openssl openssl102
   ```
4. symlinked the new version

   ```
   ln -s openssl11 openssl
   ```
5. in the appropriate build directory, i then rebuilt the target python modules under the supported version.

   ```
   python3 -m pip install --target . urllib3==1.26.15
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I specified the version of urllib3 in `requirements.txt` file.
`urllib3==1.26.15` as suggested by @devarshi-goswami in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76192376/14399624) answer.

Then I got another error `ImportError: Cannot find module named WebOb` which was resolved by specifying `WebOb==1.8.7` in the requirements.txt file.

Conclusion:
My requirements.txt file contains

```
urllib3==1.26.15
WebOb==1.8.7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what caused this error, but I could fix it by importing `boto3` into my function's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing this issue, what worked for me is that I have installed `urllib` version 1.26.16 locally and made zip out of it, then added this zip in layers. I have used this in combination with openai and it worked since we are adding dependencies in layers.

```
pip install openai urllib3==1.26.16
```